# jquery responsive .width not seeming to want to work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstraps affix top to have my nav become sticky after scrolling 350px and have my nav positioned 350px from the top with data-offset-top="350". The problem is when I go mobile I don't want the the offset top at all. I've been trying to inject and take it out with jquery but my site doesn't seem to be responding to the jquery.

Does anyone have any advice or can point out the flaw in my code?

Jquery

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(this).width() < 728) {
    $("#main-nav").removeAttr("data-offset-top","350");
  } else {
    $("#main-nav").attr("data-offset-top","350");
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<header class="jumbotron">
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div class="container-fluid ad-container">
      <h1 class="text-center">Color Fun Run!</h1>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary center-block">Register Now!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <nav id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="350">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="navbar-header">

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      </div>

      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li id="logo" class="hidden-xs site-logo">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="navigation-padding nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="visible-xs"><a href="#eventme">Event Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#events">Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>

      </div>
    </nav>
</div>

</div>
</header>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about setting .affix to position:static instead of fixed for smaller devices.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .affix {
        position: static;
    }
}
```

This will make the nav to be static instead of fixed for small devices. No Jquery required.

Working Plnkr: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/f5z421cFzHjXkWcNpPGW?p=preview)

**EDIT:** *(Above fix will make your navbar static, in case you still want to keep it fixed, remove change suggested above and use below)*

.affix applies position fixed when you reach data-offset-top value however navbar-fixed-top has already applied position fixed in case of mobile device so it wont cause any issue. Just apply navbar-fixed-top class to nav for mobile device only and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately its not the .affix I'm having the problem with its the data-offset-top of 350. So in mobile instead of my header being fixed top at load its being pushed 350px down until it is scrolled past and then its becoming fixed. I want it to be fixed top when loaded in mobile.

Comment: @Jleibham How about adding navbar-fixed-top in nav only for mobile device using jquery? Remove the affix css change suggested.

Comment: That could be possible, but I think as Zhuzhik suggested below I would still run into the problem that the attribute data-offset-top has already been initialized. I'm trying to think of away to do it in css so I can push the nav bar down to 350px but remove the css when I'm in mobile. Got any ideas?

Comment: .affix applies position fixed when you reach data-offset-top value however navbar-fixed-top has already applied position fixed in case of mobile device so it wont cause any issue. Just apply navbar-fixed-top class to nav for mobile device only and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Jleibham if this fixes the issue for you let me know I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Jleibham Glad it worked! I have updated the answer.

Comment: One more quick question. Right now I have my Jquery making these changes when resizing the page. How would I apply them based on the width loaded?

Comment: Nevermind I think I got it   

if($(window).width() <= 743){
  // do your stuff
}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the plugin has been initialized on this attribute and the event hanging on the element. Therefore, removing the attribute does not help. Try to initialize the plugin through JavaScript instead of attributes.

Comment: Hmm would you mind explaining more of how to go about that?